# Multivariable-calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

[image]

The task is the attached image. We got the function and the domain of definition. The task is to decide the function´s lowest value and biggest value plus the range. 
Lowest value should be -sqrt3,6 and the biggest value should be 108. How do I get there?

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: yes but I don´t know how to practise it

Answer (score 0):

First let's find the critical points in the interior of $D_f$, we have
\begin{align*}
  D_xf(x,y) &= 12x^2 - y^2\\
  D_yf(x,y) &= -2xy
\end{align*}
So critical points have $-2xy = 12x^2-y^2 = 0$, in the interior of $D_f$ which is 
$$  D^\circ_f = \{(x,y) \mid x > 0, x^2 + y^2 < 9\} $$
we have $x \ne 0$, so we must have $y = 0$, giving $12x^2 = 0$, so there are no critical points in the interior.

On the "lower" boundary $x=0$, $-3 \le y \le 3$, we have $f(x,y) = f(0,y) = 0$, so $f$'s maximal and minimal value here is $0$.

On the "upper" boundary, $x > 0$, $x^2 + y^2 = 9\iff y^2 = 9-x^2$, we have
$$ f(x,y) = f\bigl(x, \pm\sqrt{9-x^2}\bigr) = 4x^3 - x(9-x^2) = 5x^3 - 9x $$
So we have to find the extremal values of $g(x) = 5x^3 - 9x$ on $[0,3]$. We have $g'(x) = 15x^2 - 9$, giving $x_0 = \frac{3}{\sqrt{15}}$ as critical point. The value of $g$ here is
$$ g(x_0) = \frac{5\cdot 27}{15 \sqrt{15}} - \frac{27}{\sqrt{15}} = -\frac{54}{\sqrt{15}}
$$
So that's $f$'s minimum, $f$'s maximum is $g$'s maximum 
$$ f(3,0) = g(3) = 5\cdot 27 - 27 = 108. $$

Comment: You won the typing competition :)

Comment: f´s minimum should be -sqrt3,6 @martini

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I summarize a possible approach to the exercise. The given function $f$ is continuous on $D_f$ which is compact in $\mathbb R^2$; we know that $f$ admits maximum/minimum on $D_f$. Setting $\nabla f=0$ we arrive at the point $(0,0)$: can you find out whether it is a maximum/ minimum or a saddle point  for $f$ (have a look at the Hessian matrix $Hf(0,0)$)?

We are left to consider the restriction $f_{\partial D_f}$ of $f$ on the boundary $\partial D_f=\{(0,y),~y\in[-3,3]\}\cup \{ (x, 9-x^2), ~x\in[0,3]\}$ of $D_f$. Draw a picture of $D_f$ to understand the boundary structure.
Note that $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y\in[-3,3]$, so only the restriction to the second boundary component, i.e.

$$f(x,9-x^2)= 4x^3-x(9-x^2)= 5x^3-9x $$

deserves some analysis. Study the extrema of $f(x,9-x^2)$  and finish the proof.